# Dúvida Flutter: ListView dados duplicados

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia!

Alguém poderia me auxiliar em uma dúvida?

- **O que estou fazendo:**

Fiz um `search` para o usuário pesquisar por uma Infração no app, e logo após a ação no teclado eu redireciono ele para outra página (FiltroInicioView) passando os dados como parâmetro.

```
    onFieldSubmitted: (string) {
      print(filterNomeInfracao);
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => FiltroinicioView(filterNomeInfracao),
        ),
      );
    },
```

Após, redirecionar o usuário para a pagina de View da infração pesquisada,
Eu mostro a Lista das Infrações dentro de um **ListView.Builder**,
passando um return na lista() e passando o **filterNomeInfracao[index]** (Aqui ele vai me trazer todos os dados), e passando uma **String** chamada '**INFRAÇÕES**'

```
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Lista(
              filterNomeInfracao[index],
              'INFRAÇÕES'
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

E em seguida dentro Do BuildContext (Código de cima) eu faço a chamada para renderizar a Lista que no caso seria um card, como está abaixo:

```
class Lista extends StatelessWidget {
  final Infracao infracao;
  final txtInfracoes;

  Lista(this.infracao, this.txtInfracoes);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
  children:  <Widget>[
    Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(txtInfracoes))),
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(infracao.descricao),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

E nisso ele faz a listagem das infrações conforme a imagem do print,
POREM, como podem observar a **String** "**INFRAÇÕES**" está repetindo,
ou seja eu precisava que fosse um campo fixo, por exemplo:

```
INFRAÇÕES
E aqui todas descrições
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **O RESULTADO ESPERADO SERIA ENTÃO COM A STRING INFRAÇÕES COMO FIXO:**

Print(feito no paint) abaixo do resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está repetindo. *Infração* e *Anexos* estão sendo definidos em lista (manualmente)

Comment: Eu precisava que Infração e Anexos fossem fixo

Comment: Mostra todo a sua classe... Como você está carregando os dados na `filterNomeInfracao`? Pense se fosse você auxiliando alguém, conseguiria dizer qual o problema sem ver todo o contexto? [Edita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/458288/edit) a sua pergunta e de mais informações

Comment: Bom dia, Matheus.
Detalhei bem mais a pergunta se puder dar uma conferida

Comment: Cara, fez uma boa editando. Mas veja que eu também perguntei o seguinte _"Como você está carregando os dados na filterNomeInfracao?"_, teu código exibido aparentemente está tudo OK,o problema provavelmente é onde você está pegando os dados da sua API e carregando na variável `filterNomeInfracao`. Então de duas uma, ou você está trazendo repetido da sua API ou não está carregando certo na variável do filtro.

Comment: Então não envolve a API se vc observar estou chamando infracao.descricao (esse sim vem da API) mais a string como opode observar la em cima que eu passa uma string Text(Infrações) e chamo ela na lista é a STRING que repete e não meus dados da API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está setando o texto "INFRAÇÕES" de forma fixa a cada item da lista... Faça o seguinte:

```
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text("Infrações")
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: filterNomeInfracao.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Lista(
              filterNomeInfracao[index]
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),

class Lista extends StatelessWidget {
  final Infracao infracao;

  Lista(this.infracao);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
  children:  <Widget>[
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(infracao.descricao),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

Dessa forma irá funcionar corretamente.

Agora se você quer os itens na grid agrupados por "títulos", ai é outra história que foge da sua pergunta... Mas tu pode utilizar o packge [grouped_list](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)